# htaccess rewrite drive me nuts

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use a rather simple rewrite, something like this:

```
RewriteRule monitor.html index.php/\?first_category_id=B008 [NC,L]
```

But it doesn't work as expected, goes to like index.php/monitor.html (which kicks in symfony's routing and returns a 404 error but this is a different story)
However if i include full url like:

```
RewriteRule monitor.html http://example.com/index.php/\?first_category_id=B008 [NC,L]
```

it responses the correct content, but this looks like a full redirect, the rewrited url is revealed in the browser. And thats not transparent nor easily deployable.
What am i missing here?

the rest of the htaccess file if it matters:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Is the "rest" before or after the rule you ask?

Comment: After. The problematic rule is the first.

Comment: It's in the docroot of course.

Comment: `.htaccess` in the docroot is still a per-directory context, however.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule is outputting a relative path and you're in a per-directory context. You need `RewriteBase`. In a per-directory context, rewriting is being done on expanded filesystem paths, not on the original URL's. But the results of the expansion are converted to a URL again! `RewriteBase` supplies the prefix needed to do that. Without it, the URL is naively made out of the same filesystem prefix that was stripped prior to the substitution and you end up with for instance `http://example.com/var/www/docroot/blah...` which is nonsense. Either `RewriteBase` or put out an absolute, beginning with a slash.

Also, you should anchor the match:

```
RewriteRule ^monitor.html$ ...
```

Otherwise the rule will potentially match somewhere in the middle of the path and just that matching part will be replaced with the substitution! You don't want to match and translate `amonitor.htmly/foobar`, right, and convert just the `monitor.html` part to a the `index.php` stuff.

You should not escape the question mark in the substitution. It's not a regexp! Just `index.php/?etc` not `index.php/\?etc` (Could that backslash be what is screwing up, causing `index.php/monitor.html'?)